# How to convert a DataGridView to List

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've tried the following:

Compile error (on last As)

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Object)
myList = dataGridView.DataSource As List<Object>
```

Throws *Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource*:

```
myList = dataGridView.DataSource
```

DataSource is a `System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>` where T is a custom class.

Comment: What is the current data source for the grid?

Comment: If you have a DataSource there usually isnt a good reason to convert to a List, least of all a `List(Of Object)`.  Whatever it is bound to is already a typed collection of some sort.

Comment: @Plutonix: That may very well be. I have a DataGridView and am trying to get that data into an EPPlus ExcelWorksheet. Maybe that should have been the question.

Comment: @LarsTech: DataSource is 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'

Comment: Then what is the DataSource for your BindingSource?

Comment: DataSource is a custom class. Added it to original question.

Comment: Actually, that's incorrect. I changed the original again.

Comment: Is the grid's DataSource coming from that List(Of Project) collection in the Description class?  Do you have a BindingSource that is using a BindingList(Of Description) as it's DataSource, and then the grid is using that BindingSource?  Why aren't you posting that code?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your last comment (after posting my own answer). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of Object) ' Of MyClass?
For Each myClass As MyClass In dataGridView.DataSource
    MyList.Add(myClass )
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
myList = dataGridView.Rows.OfType(Of Object).ToList()
```

Comment: This give me this compile error `OfType is not a member of DataGridViewRowCollection`